# Semantical Error Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Hi I have an Entity name: Template
it containing 5-6 field with respective their getter/setter, defined.

But I am getting an semantical error as follows while fething data from this entity:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="message_type", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $messageType;
```

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 20 near 'message_type,': Error: Class MyuBundle\Entity\MyTemplate. has no field or association named message_type.

even the field "message_type"  already defined in my entity and table in db.

any suggestion what could be the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to see the formType thats throwing the error to be 100%.

but looking at the snippet, you don't actually have a property `message_type` on that class.  (the column name itself isn't used in mapping).

The likely error is caused by the fact that you've mapped a form field against a fieldname of `message_type` when it should be `messageType`.

provided you have a getter and setter for it you should be fine.

```
public function getMessageType()

public function setMessageType()
```

> even the field "message_type" already defined in my entity and table in db.

this is not actually the case.

Comment: these are methods:

    public function setMessageType($messageType)
    {
        $this->messageType = $messageType;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMessageType()
    {
        return $this->messageType;
    }
Actualy, I am not using FormType for this.

Comment: yes but in the formType class that youve obviously made, youve mapped it against `message_type`, which doesnt exist.

Comment: There should be "FormType", But I did not create any form type, is it possible without FormType. I am using my custom HTML

Comment: So what is the solution for this. what should I do?

Comment: I have created Form Type also:

class TemplateType extends AbstractType
{
   
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('template_id', 'hidden')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('message_type');

    }
}
Still it throwing the same error.

Comment: `->add('messageType')`. You dont have a field `message_type`

Comment: its working now, thanks , actualy i was missing the correct field mapping in DataTable